# comparing values while operator overloading in cpp

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

This might be a stupid question but when overloading an operator for example:

```
bool operator<(const node & a, const node & b){
  return a.value() < b.value();
}
```

It just compares the values and returns true if a is smaller than b right? Is this a correct way to do it?

edit: before everybody starts being angry: I'm using it to for my priority queue in my A* implemenation where the node with the smaller fscore has the highest priority

edit2: i've changed the > to < because it's better

Comment: It's the *less than* operator. Think about it...

Comment: I'm using it to for my priority queue in my A* implemenation where the node with the smaller fscore has the highest priority

Comment: Well, yes, what else should it do?

Comment: i don't see how you don't see a question here! But let me rephrase it for you; is this correct? You see my question mark: that makes it a question; thank for the people who helped. Some people are really frustrated..i get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and people will hate you for it, because you're overloading `<` but returning `>`...

Comment: that's not necessary wrong is it? because i'm using it to for my priority queue in my A* implemenation where the node with the smaller fscore has the highest priority

Comment: @ThomasVerbeke I wouldn't use an `operator<` for this, but a comparator object. Overloading operators should be intuitive, and in this case, it's not.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Agreed, and I'd add plenty of comments and meaningful variable names.

Comment: @ThomasVerbeke In this case you want your priority queue to extract the node with the smaller score (by setting a corresponding comparator). You surely don't want the node with the smaller score to be the node with the larger score. The fact is that the ordering is part of the particular algorithm or the particular priority queue and not of the data type itself. The only ordering that would make sense to be inherent to the data type is the one everybody would expect when using `a < b` (if that even exists is another question).

Comment: I understand that using operator overloading in this case is probably not the best thing to do; but do I even have choice because when I remove it it gives me the no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__x < __y’ error which i've solved using operator overloading. Also I understand that < -- > is inconsistant; i'll change it thx